# Question of the Week #32

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

It's been a while since we posted a QOTW. In large part this is because I (the editor of the QOTW section of the blog) have been extremely busy with school, and haven't had much time for writing. I'd like to get the QOTW going again though, so submit your ideas! Even if we don't do a super-detailed post about each one, it's not too hard to write a very brief summary of the top voted question from the week and mention it on the blog.

Now we're into week 32 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: Am I a bad person if I want to post http://superuser.com/questions/351638/how-to-prevent-alert-boxes-appearing-on-my-desktop?

Comment: @Shinrai oh. Oh my. Not exactly what we want to be promoting as a high-quality question to honor, but... um wow.

Comment: They see me trollin'... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Which of the Windows updates are really necessary?](https://superuser.com/questions/349866/which-of-the-windows-updates-are-really-necessary)

> I downloaded a lot of Windows updates in the automatic mode.
>
> Are they all necessary? Can I remove some of them?
>
> How do I know which ones are necessary

A lot of people probably wonder this: do I *really* need to download all 50 updates? My precious bandwidth! Ranon's answer goes into some good detail about the different types of updates and how important they are. A blog post about this might optionally talk a bit about WSUS for managing updates, and various update-packaging software (do those still exist?) so you don't have to re-download on every machine.

I won't have time to write about this in detail, but if it wins and nobody else picks it up, I'll post a quick summary to the blog.